# Bitbucket Pipelines / Extend script for each specific branch

Tags: yaml, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

For example I have the following step definition in my pipeline:

```
steps:
        - step: &test-step
            name: Test variables
            script: &test-script
                - echo ${SERVER_PIMCORE_STAGING}
```

Now I want to override the SERVER_PIMCORE_STAGING variable for each specific branch I have.

What I tried in pipelines->branches:

```
pipeline-test-262:
            - step: *test-step
              script:
                - export SERVER_PIMCORE_STAGING='123'
                - *test-script
```

Unfortunately that did not work.
Only the echo from the definitions where executed with the initially set variable content